# Installation for Aldebaran Robotics Nao for RosJava

Tags: ros, nao-robot, rosjava, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to work with the Nao Robot. I am fairly new to this and I want to use RosJava in conjunction with this.

On this guide (http://www.aldebaran-robotics.com/documentation/dev/java/compiling_examples.html#java-compiling-examples), it shows a Jar file called "jnaoqi.jar" added within the library. But it does not say where I can get this jar file. How to I get it?

Also, could anyone recommend me any installation guides for this? (I have RosJava installed already)

Thank you,
Really appreciate it

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52828/installation-for-aldebaran-robotics-nao-for-rosjava/) by [JustARandomGuy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3963/justarandomguy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2013-01-20

Post score: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your question is offtopic to ROS Answers, since the naoqi software is specfic to the Nao robot and not directly related to ROS. Also, in the future please tag your posts, this makes it easier for people to find them and more likely for you to get an answer. Please read the [support guidelines](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Support) before posting.

To answer your question(s), jnaoqi.jar is included with the NAOqi Java SDK, which you can find on the DVD that's shipped with the robot, or you can download it from Aldebaran's User site.

For using ROS with the NAO, [this page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Nao) looks like the right place to start.

---

Originally posted by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) with karma: 446 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) on 2013-01-20**:
For direct support regarding the Nao robot, I would also suggest using the Aldebaran forums.